# Index Match Sum with multiple column criteria

Tags: excel

I have the following `INDEX` `MATCH` `SUM` formula. It's only picking up the first criteria (ie. `"Actual01"`). How do I get it to pick up the other `Actuals`?

`=SUM(INDEX(Sheet1!$N$2:$S$1011,MATCH(B40&"-"&$D$5,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$1011,0),MATCH({"Actual01","Actual02","Actual03","Actual04","Actual05","Actual06"},Sheet1!$N$1:$S$1,0)))`

Comment: N$1:$S$1 that makes 6 columns. then why do you need match for those 6 value array? .. Simply sum for column N to S that you already referred in Index formula? .. Array (CSE) formula `=SUM(IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$1011=B40&"-"&$D$5,Sheet1!$N$2:$S$1011))`

Comment: Why not “Actual*” ?